# Div positioning tutorial for beginners

Tags: html

I am a programmer, not a designer and I don't like writing html and css code. I was using table's for layout for a long time. Now, I want to break this bad practice and start using div's in my website. This was a very important decision for me. Because I really *hate* using div's.

As always, I started reading written code to understand how positioning of divs work, which is the best way for me to learn something new. However, I really couldn't understand. I think there is something wrong. It shouldn't have been that hard, I really think. This div "*API*" is written wrong, should have been simpler. However, I know that this discussion is non-sense.

I'm now confused with the usage of the following items,

```
float, clear, inline, block, position, relative, absolute
```

I'm looking for web-sites, stackoverflow posts, tutorials for learning div's for beginners who have a programming background like me.

PS: I checked w3's CSS standards. However, it is too long and detailed. I want something shorter, easier to understand for pragmatical purposes.

Comment: also, remember, Google is your best friend

Comment: Currently, my best friend is table's, sadly.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but there are already so many tutorials for this (over the last 10+ years) that it's hard to believe there has to be SO "help me google this" question.

Comment: @Bo5ao/Dampe Google search on this topic brought me here. Stop trolling.

Answer (score 3):

When I was teaching myself HTML I spent a lot of time on W3Schools website. I simply cannot find a better place to learn HTML and CSS. Here is a sample code that demonstrates how float works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img 
{
float:right;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>In the paragraph below, we have added an image with style <b>float:right</b>. The result is that the image will float to the right in the paragraph.</p>
<p>
<img src="http://vsual.co/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/HumanRightsLogo_CO.jpg" width="95" height="84" />
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.

</p>
</body>

</html>
```

If you are still unsure please fell free to visit [W3Schools link 1](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) and [W3Schools Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float)

I hope this helps

Comment: Whilst w3schools *might* be ok for the simple stuff, I recommend against it. They appear at the top because they pay for that spot- not because they are the best. For more info, http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: @SacredSkull I am aware of it however if a tutorial is short and concise why wasting "precious" time digging around when you can use w3s. I am not saying it is good or bad but it's simply a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out the articles on  http://net.tutsplus.com and the related webdesign.tutsplus site.

On their network there's also a very good introduction course on CSS, but it's not free.

Anyway it's not hard at all.

You have a few types of elements: block, inline and online-block you'll use most. Others will be used as well as defaults.

Divs are block elements, so they normally take the while weight of their parent element and as much height as they need. To form complex layouts and columns sometimes we use float, which changes this by placing the div out of the page flow so other elements stack next to it.

That's a really rough and perhaps not accurate enough description, but should serve as a starting point.

Also definitely check this out: http://learnlayout.com
It's an awesome explanation of CSS layouts by example.

I hope this will help you find your way around.